# FluentNHibernate configuration, NotSupportedException at DBConnection.GetSchema()

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sql-server-ce

Trying to configure **SQL Ce** database, and get the following exception on **BuildSessionFactory()**.

Same configuration works for **SQLite**, but I've not used SQLCe before with NHibernate.

Any suggestions?

References:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe  3.5.1.0
FluentNHibernate 1.2
NHibernate 3.1
```

Configuration:

```
        Dim fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure() _
       .Database(MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connectionString)) _
        .Mappings(Function(m) m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf(Of InstrumentMap)() _
                      .Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultLazy.Never())) _
        .ExposeConfiguration(Function(c) InlineAssignHelper(cfg, c)) _
        .Cache(Function(c) c.UseQueryCache())

    sessionFactory = fluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()
```

Exception in DBConnection.cs, at:

```
        virtual public DataTable GetSchema(string collectionName) {
            throw ADP.NotSupported(); 
        }
```

> System.NotSupportedException occurred
>     Message=Specified method is not supported.
>     Source=System.Data
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.GetSchema(String collectionName)
>     InnerException:

Btw; I get same exception if I omit the .ExposeConfiguration(..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetSchema is not supported by 3.5, but SQL Server Compact 4.0 supports GetSchema

Comment: Thanks! Though.. I'm not aware what actually calls GetSchema.. How would I change the configuration to work for 3.5?

Comment: I assume NHibernate calls GetSchema somewhere, and there is not fix other than not using FluentConfig or change to 4.0 I would imagine

Answer (score 1):

GetSchema() is called by Hibernate during startup. In its default settings it tries to determine if the db schema is still suitable.
If the schema differs, Hibernate is capable to update the schema -- if the database is capable to report its current schema.
As Erik already state: SQL CE is not capable to report the current schema...
Hence, it is not a problem of Fluent itself.

So I see the following alternatives for you:

1. Get rid of the exception
   a. Catch and ignore
   b. Prevent that Hibernate calls SchemaUpdate.Execute(),
     but SchemaExport.Create() (if you would like your schema to be created)
     When looking at your code, this most probably can be done in InlineAssignHelper?!
2. Get rid of SQL CE ;-)
3. Switch to SQL CE 4.0

Regards,
Seven